# How do I get my yarn/jest test to pass in gitbash?

Tags: reactjs

I am new to jest/yarn testing and im doing a basic test. I'm trying to see if my Class/Component App has the text of "Baseball Scoreboard" which it does. How do I get my test to pass?

App.test.js

```
 import React from 'react';
   import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
   import 'jest-dom/extend-expect';
   import App from "./App"


   test(" ", () => {
      const expected = render(<App />);
      expected.getByText("Baseball Scoreboard")

  });
```

App.js

```
 import React from 'react';
   import React from 'react';
import Display from "./Display"


class App extends React.Component{
    render(){
    return (
      <div>
          <h2>Baseball Scoreboard</h2>
      <Display />
    </div>
  );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

With React testing library and Jest it'd look smth like this:

```
it("should have 'Baseball Scoreboard' text", () => {
  const { getByText } = render( < App / > );
  expect(getByText("Baseball Scoreboard")).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

More info in the [documentation](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/intro).